# plotting a two by five cell in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, cell

I would like to plot the cell 'Transmission' column 1 on the x axis and column 2 on the y axis (see image also). I have tried some suggestions found by searching in the forum and on the internet without success.

[image: image of the cell in matlab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, hopefully it's what you wanted. I put a screenshot of what it outputs below as well. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/39990-how-to-put-strings-on-the-x-axes) for reference.

```
Transmission = {'10eV.dat',400;'11eV.dat',488;'12eV.dat',406;'8eV.dat',391;'9eV.dat',500};
FIG = figure;
axes1 = axes('Parent',FIG,'XTickLabel',Transmission(:,1));
box(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'all');
plot(1:length(Transmission),cell2mat(Transmission(:,2)));
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, yes it worked that way!  i'll try to plot a bar chart with the data probably more comprehensive that way. cheers

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
transmission=cell2mat(transmission)
plot(transmission(:,1),transmission(:,2));
```

As far as I know you can´t plot cells without extracting the data.

Comment: i have indeed tried this. I get an error "Not enough input arguments"

Comment: what code did you use ? and in which line do you get the error ?

Comment: i used: `plot(Transmission(:,1),Transmission(:,2))`

Comment: and the cell2mat line ? did you check that you write transmission constantly with a capital letter ?

Comment: using cell2mat gives out an error `Error using cell2mat (line 45)
All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.`